# Не работает JQuery в Codeception Selenium 2.47.1 WebDriver

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Не проходит тест в Codeception Selenium WebDriver.

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->amOnPage('/index.html');
$I->executeJS('return $(window).trigger($.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 39 }));');
```

Пишет следующию ошибку:

```
yuri@localhost /v/w/r/test (landing)> php ./vendor/bin/codecept run
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.1.2
Powered by PHPUnit 4.8.9 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Acceptance Tests (2) -----------------------------------------------------------
Perform actions and see result (GitHubCept)                               Ok
WelcomeCept                                                               Error
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Unit Tests (0) ------------------------------
---------------------------------------------

Functional Tests (0) ------------------------
---------------------------------------------


Time: 11.46 seconds, Memory: 13.50Mb

There was 1 error:

---------
1) WelcomeCept (tests/acceptance//WelcomeCept.php)


  [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException] $ is not defined
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'localhost', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.1.6-200.fc22.x86_64+debug', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown  


Scenario Steps:

 2. $I->executeJS("$(window).trigger($.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 39 }));")
 1. $I->amOnPage("/index.html")

#1  /var/www/rabota.redcube.loc/test/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:287
#2  /var/www/rabota.redcube.loc/test/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:507
#3  /var/www/rabota.redcube.loc/test/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:286
#4  Codeception\Module\WebDriver->executeJS
#5  /var/www/rabota.redcube.loc/test/tests/_support/_generated/AcceptanceTesterActions.php:2312
#6  /var/www/rabota.redcube.loc/test/tests/acceptance/WelcomeCept.php:32

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

P.S. Простой JS код проходит тест
P.S.S. JQuery  подключен в консоли браузера все нормально отрабатывает

Comment: Я так понимаю, что executeJS() просто не видит Jquery, если в консоли браузера Jquery нормально выполняется, но как его подключить?

Comment: Сделал так, но теперь тест просто виснет

$Jquery = "'<script src=\"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js\"></script>'";
$I->executeJS("document.write(".$Jquery.")");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил следующим путем:

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->amOnPage('/index.html');
$I->executeJS("
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js';
    document.head.appendChild(script);
");
$I->executeJS('$(window).trigger($.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 39 }))');
```